# When filing jointly, does it matter whose bank account is used to pay?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

If both the wife and husband filed jointly, does it matter whose account we use to pay taxes due?

Comment: On a typical US income tax Return, **most of the tax due** has already been sent to the IRS via tax withholding, and these amounts are shown on the W2 form(s) that the spouses **receive** from their employers. These amounts need to be added up and the total reported on the tax return. If any additional amount is due, a check for this amount needs to be sent (usually to a different address than the one that receives your tax return). The IRS doesn't care _which_ bank account this check is drawn on, as long as it is honored. If one spouse refuses to pay, the IRS will collect the entire amount...

Comment: from the other spouse: no halfsies there. On a joint return, each spouse is jointly and severally (meaning individually) liable for the _entire_ amount of unpaid taxes. You cannot claim that you paid your half of the amount due and tell the IRS to collect the other half from your spouse.

Comment: @teja - you've asked a series of very basic questions. Do you mind updating your profile with a bit of information, location, marital  status , for example, so we can better help you?

Comment: Thank you when it is necessary sure I don't hesitate to ask you.

Comment: Any how I am single not married

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whichever account you put on your filing; it doesn't really matter. I file the taxes for my wife and I (married - joint), and I pay the taxes from my checking account because I choose to, but I could use my wife's account. When filing jointly, the IRS doesn't really care which account the money comes from, or goes back into. As with you other question: [Question about married couple filing jointly](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/64167/question-about-married-couple-filing-jointly/64168#64168)  I think you need to get a better understanding of how to file taxes in general. If you use a tool like TurboTax or HR Block or Tax Slayer (or one of the others), they will basically walk you through it.

One item that may come up is that you may both need to be listed on the account in order to receive a refund. Payment to the IRS doesn't matter, but I believe when receiving funds, filing jointly, the receiving account needs both names on it.

Comment: @teja , you're welcome. If this answer meets your needs, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @teja It looks like you've already accepted it, but maybe someone did it on your behalf (didn't know that was possible). When you want to mark an answer as accepted, you can hit the check-mark icon under the up/down voting buttons.